# Google Charts Multiple Annotations

Tags: google-visualization

Per my company's requirements, we want our column labels to be along the bottom of the chart.  In Google Charts, you can accomplish this with the following:

```
view.setColumns([0,
{ calc: "stringify",
sourceColumn: 2,
type: "string",
role: "annotation" },
1,
]);
```

Notice that the annotation role comes before the bars that it will be labeling.  Thus, the annotation is annotating the horizontal axis, and voila! Your annotations are along the bottom of the chart.

Here's where my problem comes in.  I actually want this particular chart to have TWO annotations.  One for my columns (along the bottom), and another annotation for a second line.  I thought this would be a simple matter of something like this:

```
view.setColumns([0,
{ calc: "stringify",
sourceColumn: 2,
type: "string",
role: "annotation" },
1,
3,
{ calc: "stringify",
sourceColumn: 4,
type: "string",
role: "annotation" },
]);
```

However, doing this seemingly simple setup resulted in "Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node'" error from Google Charts.  With a little testing I realized that the failure was the combination of trying to have the first annotation on the horizontal axis + have a second annotation.

Unfortunately, my work demands that this be exactly how these charts look.  How can I have two annotations on the same chart where one annotation is along the horizontal axis, and the other annotation is in its usual spot?

Comment: That should work, but I tested it, and it doesn't, so it looks like you've found a bug.  I submitted a bug report on it [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1514), you can "star" the issue to get updates on a fix.  In the meantime, as a work-around, you can add a row of null values to the DataTable as the first row, eg: `data.addRow([null, null, null, null, null]);`.  Doing this stops the error and your chart should draw as normal.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding a row of 'nulls' results in the same error.  I ended up getting this to work by adding a row of nulls, and setting the value in position [1] to " ".  For some reason, setting the value in position [1] stops the error from happening.